# "Build path entry is missing" after moving my workspace directory location

Tags: eclipse, jar, classpath, buildpath

I use Eclipse and manually moved my workspace (cut and paste) from `/home/user/workspace` to `/home/user/somefolder/workspace`.

I rebooted Eclipse and I get build path errors. I open up the build path of one of the projects with this error and see `Build path entry is missing: home/user/workspace/SomeProject/lib/cloning-1.9.0.jar`.

This is clearly a bug in eclipse since I told it where my new workspace was located when i rebooted. How do I fix this (without doing it manually for one Jar since it's an error with many).

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you added it to a Java Buildpath as an External jar--it then recorded on the on-disk location rather than the in-workspace path. The Java Build Path is stored in the .classpath files in each project. If necessary, you can use Search->File to do a search and replace.